The line $2x - y + 1 = 0$ is tangent to a circle at point $(2, 5),$ and the center of the circle lies on the line $x - 2y = 4$. Find radius of circle.

The line $2x - y + 1 = 0$ is tangent to a circle at point $(2, 5),$ and the center of the circle lies on the line $x - 2y = 4$. Find radius of circle.

Solution Attempt Using $T = 0$ Method:
The general equation of a circle is:
$x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$.
The equation of the tangent at a point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the circle is given by:
$T = xx_0 + yy_0 + g(x_0 + x) + f(y_0 + y) + c = 0$.
Substituting the point of tangency $(2, 5)$ into the formula:
$T = 2x + 5y + g(2 + x) + f(5 + y) + c = 0$.
Expanding this:
$2x + 5y + 2g + gx + 5f + fy + c = 0$.
Comparing with the given tangent $2x - y + 1 = 0$, we equate coefficients:
Coefficient of $x$: $2 + g = 2 \implies g = 0$.
Coefficient of $y$: $5 + f = -1 \implies f = -6$.
Constant term: $2g + 5f + c = 1 \implies 0 + (-30) + c = 1 \implies c = 31$.
Thus, the equation of the circle becomes:
$x^2 + y^2 - 12y + 31 = 0.$
The center of this circle is $(0, 6)$. Substituting into the given condition $x - 2y = 4$:
$0 - 2(6) = -12 \neq 4$.
This shows that the center does not satisfy the condition, making the result invalid.
Using this incorrect center $(0, 6)$, the radius comes out to be:
$r = \sqrt{(0 - 2)^2 + (6 - 5)^2} = \sqrt{4 + 1} = \sqrt 5$.
This radius is inconsistent with the book's answer.
Solution Using Normal Method:
The normal to the circle at $(2, 5)$ passes through the center. The slope of the tangent is $2$, so the slope of the normal is $-\frac12$.
The equation of the normal passing through $(2, 5)$ is:
$y - 5 = -\frac12(x - 2)$,
which simplifies to:
$x + 2y - 12 = 0$.
The center also lies on the line $x - 2y = 4$. Solving these two equations:
$x + 2y - 12 = 0$,
$x - 2y = 4$,
we get the center as $(8, 2)$.
The radius is then calculated using the distance between the center $(8, 2)$ and the point of tangency $(2, 5)$:
$r = \sqrt{(8 - 2)^2 + (2 - 5)^2} = \sqrt{36 + 9} = \sqrt{45} = 3\sqrt 5$. The $T = 0$ method leads to an incorrect answer because the derived center does not satisfy the condition $x - 2y = 4$. However, solving using the normal method gives a radius of $3\sqrt 5$, matching the book’s answer.Despite the correct radius using the normal method, the inconsistency in the $T = 0$ method raises questions about the problem. Either the question is designed to favor one specific approach, or there is an overlooked detail causing this discrepancy. Further clarification or validation is needed to confirm the problem's correctness.
I understand this is a long post, but I would really appreciate it if you could take some time to share your thoughts and clarify whether there’s something we’re overlooking or if the problem is indeed incorrect. Your help would be invaluable!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Won't it just be the distance from the given point to the line on which the center lies?

@Henriksupportsthecommunity the corresponding radius doesnt have to perpendicular right

You have made the silliest of errors. You actually need to solve $\frac{2+g}{2}=\frac{5+f}{-1}=\frac{2g+f+c}{1}$ if you are claiming the two equations to be of the same line. The coefficients of x,y and the independent term must be proportional and not equal.

@Maverick Well, I did.., But it's not working..You can try..Maybe, I'm doing something wrong..But I don't think there's any mistake in my calculation..

@Henriksupportsthecommunity Yeah, it will be..I have solved it..

@Ella. Probably you are not using the fact that centre $(-g,-f)$ lies on the line $x-2y=4$ which gives you another equation $-g+2f=4$ to play with in addition to $\frac{2+g}{2}=\frac{5+f}{-1}=\frac{2g+f+c}{1}$

I can't believe I overlooked these things.. Thanks alot for your help..

I have used the idea of Family of Circles.
Equation of family of circles which have the line $2x-y+1=0$ as tangent at the point $(2,5)$ on it is given by $$(x-2)^2+(y-5)^2+\lambda(2x-y+1)=0$$
The equation on simplification becomes $$x^2+y^2+2(\lambda-2)x-(\lambda+10)y+29+\lambda=0$$
whose centre is given by $\left(2-\lambda,\frac{\lambda+10}{2}\right)$
which lies on the line $x-2y=4$
$\Rightarrow(2-\lambda)-2\left(\frac{\lambda+10}{2}\right)=4$
$\Rightarrow \lambda=-6$
Centre$\equiv (8,2)$
Radius $=\sqrt{(8-2)^2+(2-5)^2}=3\sqrt{5}$

That's an amazing alternate method..However, That's not my question.. I'm asking if there's a problem in using the T=0 method, which is universally applicable

See my comment on your post

You have used the "point circle" and then generalised it, right?

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous Yes. That is one of the ways to explain it.

Alternatively: you can mark the centre of circle as $(h,k)$. Then $h=4+2k$. Further equate the distance of $(h,k)$ from the point of intersection (distance formula) and from the equation of the tangent;
$$r = \frac{\left|2h-k+1\right|}{\sqrt 5} = \sqrt{(2-h)^2 + (5-k)^2}$$
That becomes $$\left|3k + 9\right|^2 = 5(2+2k)^2 + 5(5-k)^2$$
This equation becomes $k=2$ and thus the radius is $\frac{|3(k) + 9|}{\sqrt 5} = \frac{15}{\sqrt 5} = 3\sqrt 5$.

Since the line $L_1:2x-y+1=0$ is tangent to the circle at $(2,5)$ we can find the normal at that point and the center must lie on this normal.
The normal is a perpendicular to $L_1$ so its slope must be $-\frac12$ and pass through $(2,5)$
$$L_2:x+2y-12=0$$
$L_2$ is a normal to the circle which means the center lies on $L_2$ but we know the center also lies on $L_3:x-2y=4$  so the center is the intersection of $L_2,L_3$$$C\equiv(8,2)$$
Radius is then simply distance between $(2,5)$ and $(8,2)$ $$r=3\sqrt{5}$$
Solving using $T=0$
We have the circle equation is $$x^2+y^2-2xx_1-2yy_1+C=0$$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the center.
The tangent equation at $(a,b)$ will be $$ax+by-x_1(x+a)-y_1(y+b)+C=0$$ this implies the slope $m$ is $$m=-\frac{a-x_1}{b-y_1}$$
Substituting given values you get $$a+2b=12$$ which is the same second line

I know that, I have mentioned this method in my answer..I don't think you understood what I was asking..

I was writing the T=0 solution gimme a sec

Oh, Alright ..My bad

@Ella your mistake is that you forgot the $gx,fy$ terms while equating slope
